# Globalization issue in C# windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, globalization

I am creating a windows application developed using C#.

I want the user to input some text and display it in another label on a button click event.

The text entered should be in local language Tamil.

I changed the language property of the Form element to Tamil and changed the font of the text box to the desired font and added the following piece of code to the form.

```
public Form2()
{
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ta-IN");
InitializeComponent();
}
```

The button element has the following code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text;
}
```

I can input in Tamil and display the contents in Tamil in the system where I am developing the application but when I deploy the application in another system I can not input Tamil words. The desired font is installed in the host system.

Help me out here.

Comment: Is the appropriate language pack installed on the computer that it does not work on?

Comment: Yes the pack is installed and I have installed the font too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should install language.

it might solve your problem.

For that you can go to **Control Panel\Region and Language setting\ keyboard and language tab\Install language**.

Comment: How can I do this in windowsXP

Comment: it is same for windowsXP